# nginx proxy_pass exact route to remote server

Tags: nginx

I'm currently trying to setup a proxy_pass to a remote server for an exact route with nginx. I've done this numerous times for sub-domains without any issues but can't get it to work for an exact route.

```
#sites-available/default:

server {
    root /dir;
    index index.html index.htm;
    server_name staging.domain.co;
    listen 80;

    location / {
       try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }

    location = /sitemap {
        proxy_pass http://45.77.0.0:3334;
    }
}
```

When I go to http://staging.domain.co/sitemap I get the "Cannot GET /sitemap" error rendered in the browser, with a 404 showing in the dev tools and no request reaches the remote server. The remote server works as expected and returns what it's supposed too. Also, there is no logged error in /var/log/nginx/error.log. Does anybody have an idea what could be causing this?

Comment: " I get the "Cannot GET /sitemap" error" - where you get it? What's HTTP code?

Comment: My bad, that was unclear. In the browser that error renders and a 404 shows in the dev tool

Comment: It seems some kind of non-standard message(rendered in the browser). If you haven't modify Nginx error page, then this message should be returned by upstream server. Please show output of "curl -v http://45.77.0.0:3334/sitemap"